# How to create multiple instances to an implementation of an interface?

Tags: java, guice

Let A be an interface which has a method a. 
Let B be a class which implements A and has method a and has three fields 1,2,3. 
I want to use two instances of A (meaning B), both of which have different values of 1,2,3 (present in cfg file) at two different places.

Can someone provide a simple and elegant solution to this problem using Guice.

Comment: Let C be an example of what you've tried. Let D be our feedback.

Comment: I was thinking something like - bind( A.class).annotatedWith(names.Named("something")).toInstance(new B(1,2,3));

Comment: @jameslarge I think the question is more about how you do this with DI.

Comment: @michael your D?

Comment: @biziclop yes finally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't tell how the class that uses your dependency references the interface. I assume that you want to reference it with an interface.

What you can use, is annotation that will denote which instance you want to use. Assume that these are your implementations:

```
interface A {
    void a();
}

class B implements A {
    private int value;

    void a() { ... }

    B(int value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

And these are the classes that use the implementations:

```
class UserFirst {

    private A a;

    @Inject
    UserFirst(@Named("first") A a) { this.a = a; }
}

class UserSecond {

    private A a;

    @Inject
    UserSecond(@Named("second") A a) { this.a = a; }
}
```

The thing that decides which implementation is going to be injected is the `@Named` annotation. You can also define your annotations, but usually it's an overkill.

Now, in order to bind that, you can do something like this:

```java
class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {

    A first = new B(1);
    B second = new B(2);


    bind(A.class)
        .annotatedWith(Names.named("first")).toInstance(first);

    bind(A.class)
        .annotatedWith(Names.named("second")).toInstance(second);
    }
}
```

Here's the full documentation: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations

Comment: Doesn't matter, actually. Guice doesn't care about the actual type here, as long as it can be bound to A.

Answer (score 1):

if I do understand you correctly, you might want to make B abstract so that you can override the methods which you want to change, if this is the case.

Now I can only assume that by fields you mean field-varriables. I would then recommend you to make them NON-static and change them in the constructor when you make an object. Then read the values of 1,2,3 in the public static void main method and send them upon creating a new object:

```
public class B implements A {
    private int x,y,z;

    /**
    * This would now be the constructror
    */
    public B(int x, int y, int z){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    /**
    * Then some return functions
    */
    public get1() { return this.x; }
    public get2() { return this.y; }
    public get3() { return this.z; }

    /**
    * Then whatever methods you get from A
    */
    public int someMethodFromA(int x, int y){
        return x*y;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    /**
    * Some random method to read inn from CFG file
    */

    int x1 = readXFromCFG();
    int y1 = readYFromCFG();
    int z1 = readZFromCFG();

    B objectB1 = new B(x1,y1,z1);

    int x2 = readXFromCFG();
    int y2 = readYFromCFG();
    int z2 = readZFromCFG();

    B objectB2 = new B(x2,y2,z2);

    int x3 = readXFromCFG();
    int y3 = readYFromCFG();
    int z3 = readZFromCFG();

    B objectB3 = new B(x3,y3,z3);
}
```

Comment: The method 'a' in the implementation would be the same, just the values/parameter would change. And I was asking how to inject these two different instances of B using guice

Comment: Also worth mentioning that you can NOT use 1, 2, 3 as names for variables, classes or functions or anything really so don't use them in examples either

Comment: and YES that is exactly what this will do. Let me fix on the example a bit

Comment: Yeah I know that I was just naming them so for referring sake

Comment: there. Try looking again. Now you see there will be 3 different objects B and they will all have the same function from A which works the same way. BUT they all have different field variables

Comment: Thanks for all the effort you have put but I need a solution using guice DI framework.